# Linear algebra : eigenvalues of an integral operator on polynomials

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, orthogonal-polynomials, integral-operators

Consider the linear transformation 
$$
T : \left\{
\begin{array}{ccc}
\mathbb{R}_n[X] & \to & \mathbb{R}_n[X] \\
P & \mapsto & \int_0^1 (X + t)^n\,P(t)\,dt
\end{array}\right.
$$

where $\mathbb{R}_n[X]$ denotes the vector space of polynomials with real coefficients and degree $\leqslant n$.

NB: $T$ is self-adjoint with respect to the $L^2$-inner product $\langle P, Q \rangle =  \int_0^1 P(t)\, Q(t) \,dt$.

The question is: what are the eigenvalues of $T$?

Edit: This question was originally posted by someone on the French maths forum les-mathematiques.net ([here](http://www.les-mathematiques.net/phorum/read.php?3,902947)). I do not know if there is a reason to think that it is actually possible to find an explicit expression for the eigenvalues.

Comment: You could deduce the matrix of $T$ in the basis $\{1,X,X^2,\dots,X^n\}$ and then calculate the eigenvalues of that matrix, if it is doable.

Comment: It might make life a bit easier to apply Gram-Schmidt to $\{1,X,\cdots,X^n\}$ to get an orthonormal basis of $\mathbb{R}_n[X]$, and then compute the matrix of $T$ with respect to the orthonormal basis? Then the matrix of $T$ really will be symmetric.

Comment: @Ragnar & Branimir: both ideas are natural but try to do them concretely, see if that workds for you... didn't for me.

Comment: The eigenvalue equation is a so-called fredholm equation of the second kind, for which there are some solution approaches. But I have the feeling that would be cracking a nut with a sledgehammer.

Comment: @Roland: I feel more like it cracks nothing at all...

Comment: I don't see why one would believe that an explicit expression for the eigenvalues of an $n \times n$ matrix should be possible to find. It is, after all, impossible to find the roots of a fifth degree polynomial in radicals.

Comment: @ChristopherA.Wong: Using this reasoning, it shouldn't be possible to calculate the eigenvalues of any differential operator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the adhoc convention $\frac{x}{0}=x$, Newton’s binomial formula yields

$$
T(X^j)=\sum_{i=0}^{n} \frac{\binom{n}{i}}{n+1+j-i}X^i \tag{1}
$$

If we denote by ${\cal B}_n=(1,X,X^2, \ldots, X^{n})$ the canonical
basis of ${\mathbb R}_n[X]$, the matrix $A$ of $T$ relatively to ${\cal B}_n$ is
$A=(a_{ij})_{1\leq i,j \leq n+1}$ where

$$
a_{ij}=\frac{\binom{n}{i-1}}{n+1+j-i} \tag{2}
$$

For example, when $n=4$ we have

$$
A=\left(\begin{matrix}
 \frac{1}{5} & \frac{1}{6} & \frac{1}{7} & \frac{1}{8} & \frac{1}{9} \\
\ & & & & \\
 1 & \frac{4}{5} & \frac{2}{3} & \frac{4}{7} & \frac{1}{2} \\
\ & & & & \\
 2 & \frac{3}{2} & \frac{6}{5} & 1 &  \frac{6}{7} \\  
\ & & & & \\
 2 & \frac{4}{3} & 1 & \frac{4}{5} & \frac{2}{3} \\  
\ & & & & \\
 1 & \frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{3} & \frac{1}{4} & \frac{1}{5} \\        
\end{matrix}\right)
$$

The characteristic polynomial of this $A$ is

$$\chi_A=X^5 - \frac{16}{5}X^4 - \frac{251}{450}X^3 + \frac{2977}{330750}X^2 - 
\frac{19}{1890000}X + \frac{1}{2778300000}$$

a polynomial whose Galois group over  $\mathbb Q$ is ${\mathfrak S}_5$ and
whose roots are therefore not expressible by radicals.

Thus I concur with Christopher A.Wong’s comment that it is unlikely that
a simple closed-form solution exists.

Comment: Check your indices. Also, $T(X^j)$ is not correct, there is a "+1" missing at the denominator. How did you find the Galois group?

Comment: @Seub Corrected, thanks (notice you must shift the indices by $1$ when you pass to matrix indices). To find the Galois group, I used the polgalois function of PARI-GP. You can check it for yourself at http://www.sagemath.org/

Comment: Thanks, I was not aware of this tool.

Comment: In the question, there is a note that the operator is hermitian. Why is your corresponding representing matrix not symmetric?

Comment: @Roland Easy : my matrix is not symmetric because my basis is not orthonormal. Changing bases does not change the eigenvalues, so computing the matrix in an orthonormal basis would not simplify the problem.

Comment: But maybe the structure of the matrix would give some insights if a nice basis is chosen?

Answer (score 1):

While it tuns out quickly that there is no "simple formula" for these eigenvalues one is led to look at them numerically. They are indeed real and alternate in sign, the largest one being positive. The following figure shows the results for $n=30$:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for that, interesting figure indeed.